# What is the specific meaning of the verbal phrase 'deal with'?

Tags: verbs

In this following context, what is the specific meaning of the verbal phrase 'deal with'?
Is it 'addresses' or 'manages?

Source:

> It no doubt contains an excellent ethical code which is unparalleled
> in its perfection and altruistic attitude. It deals with one way of
> life for the monks and another for the laity.

Source: P. 24
Buddhism in a Nutshell
by Narada Thera

Answer (score 1):

If "it" is a book, "deals with" means "discusses".  If "it" is a philosophy or religion, "deals with" can mean "handles" or  "approaches or regards or treats (a subject or issue)".

> The religion **deals with** "sins of the flesh" very differently than it deals with avarice.

Comment: Thanks you very much, @TimR. It has the subtitle as: "Is BUDDHISM AN ETHICAL SYSTEM? "
So it may refer to 'Buddhism'.

Comment: @SakyaKim  Whenever a sentence, which you have a question about, starts with a pronoun, include the previous sentence when asking here, so that we can be sure of the antecedent.

Comment: Thanks again TimR.